# Inverse kinematics cartesian result inaccurate

Tags: python, robotics, inverse-kinematics, pybullet

My try to simulate cartesian control with PyBullet with the help of [GitHub examples](https://github.com/bulletphysics/bullet3/blob/master/examples/pybullet/examples/inverse_kinematics.py) gives an inaccurate result when checking via forward kinematics. It seems target orientation is neglected:

```
import pybullet
import time
import pybullet_data
import numpy as np

x = [400,400,300,300,300,400,400,300,300,300]
y = [100,200,200,100,100,100,200,200,100,100]
z = [800,1500,1500,1500,1600,1500,1500,1500,1500,1600]
a = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
b = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
c = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
SimulateCartesianPositions(x,y,z,a,b,c)


def SimulateCartesianPositions(x=None, y=None, z=None, a=None, b=None, c=None, frame=None):
    cartesianPositions = PointArray = np.column_stack([x, y, z, a, b, c])
    cartesianPositions = np.array(cartesianPositions) / 1000
    physicsClient = pybullet.connect(pybullet.GUI)
    pybullet.resetSimulation()
    pybullet.setAdditionalSearchPath(pybullet_data.getDataPath())
    planeID = pybullet.loadURDF("kuka_experimental/plane/plane.urdf")
    robot = pybullet.loadURDF("kuka_experimental/kuka_kr10_support/urdf/kr10r1420.urdf", [0, 0, 0],useFixedBase=1)
    pybullet.resetBasePositionAndOrientation(robot, [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1])
    pybullet.setGravity(0, 0, -9.81)
    rp = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]

    for i in range(6):
        pybullet.resetJointState(robot, i, rp[i])

    endeffectorID = 6
    axisPositions = np.empty([np.shape(cartesianPositions)[0],6])

    for i in range(np.shape(cartesianPositions)[0]):
        axisPositions[i, :] = pybullet.calculateInverseKinematics(robot,
                                                endeffectorID,
                                                targetPosition=cartesianPositions[i,0:3],
                                                targetOrientation=pybullet.getQuaternionFromEuler(cartesianPositions[i,3:6])
                                                )
        pybullet.setJointMotorControlArray(
            robot, range(6), pybullet.POSITION_CONTROL,
            targetPositions=axisPositions[i, :])
        StartStepSimulation(robot, axisPositions[i, :])
        world_position, world_orientation = pybullet.getLinkState(robot, 2)[:2]
        print('Position:', world_position)
        print('Orientation:', world_orientation)


def StartStepSimulation(robot, targetPositions):
    currentangles = np.array([[j[0] for j in pybullet.getJointStates(robot, range(6))]])
    while np.all(np.round(currentangles, decimals=4) != np.round(targetPositions, decimals=4)):
        pybullet.stepSimulation()
        time.sleep(1. / 240.)
        currentangles = np.array([[j[0] for j in pybullet.getJointStates(robot, range(6))]])
    if not pybullet.getContactPoints():
        print('MSG: No Collision.')
    else:
        print('ERR: Collision detected!')
        print('ERR: Contact Points:', pybullet.getContactPoints())
```

I reduced GitHub examples (no null space or dampening) but get same problems. I tried with another robot model from KUKA library. Nothing changed. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The accuracy of the inverse kinematics calculation depends on the current configuration of the robot. The closer the two configurations are, the better the result will be. The [PyBullet API](https://docs.google.com/document/d/10sXEhzFRSnvFcl3XxNGhnD4N2SedqwdAvK3dsihxVUA/edit?pli=1#heading=h.9i02ojf4k3ve) exposes options to perform the IK iteratively and hence improve accuracy (see discussion on [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/bulletphysics/bullet3/issues/1380)). For example, you could try:

```
target_joint_positions = bullet_client.calculateInverseKinematics(
    robot.body_id, robot.end_effector_link_id, position, orientation,
    maxNumIterations=100, residualThreshold=0.001)
```

A higher number of iterations and lower residual threshold should get you closer to the target pose.

Alternatively, you can re-calculate the inverse kinematics after every step of the simulation, apply new motor controls, and it should get better as the robot approaches the target pose.

Unfortunately, I am missing the urdf files in your example so cannot test in your code. However, the orientation works for me as used in the command above.